# SharePoint 2016 Separate farm for Disaster Recovery preparations

Tags: 2016, disaster-recovery

SharePoint Separate farm for Disaster Recovery:
I want to Create Separate 2016 Farm in our company for Disaster recovery (DR).
What are the best practices to Prepare DR SP 2016 farm at SQL Server level?
From below which one is suitable options:

DBA Created two SQL Nodes one in DC and another one in DR, DBA given one AGLISTNER and he told use this to Connect to DC and Same for DR.
Behind AGLISTNER  DBA Created one AG and I Prepared the DC SP farm and in this AG below SP Databases created
Config,Services,Content databases.

1. Here what are the suitable options to replicate databases from DC to DR SQL

   1. Sync or Replicate SP Content Databases to DR.
   2. Replicate all SP databases including Config database, Central administration, Services & Content databases.
2. For first option is it best practice to connect DR SQL Instance directly from DR SP Servers without AGListner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DR is a complex topic, I'm going to refer you to articles on this topic which I would encourage you to read and then if you have questions, create a new Question here.

Needless to say, you shouldn't be using the same AOAG Listener as production; DR should be using async replication due to distance/latency. Typically this means you'd make a direct connection to the individual SQL node at the DR site from your DR SharePoint farm. Recall that each member server as part of a farm, SharePoint and SQL, need to have a 1ms response time and 1Gbps connectivity between each node.

For #2, Config and Admin databases cannot be replicated and re-used on a second farm nor should some other databases be replicated, such as the Usage database (this should not be replicated between SQL nodes even in production).

[High availability and disaster recovery concepts in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-concepts)

[Supported high availability and disaster recovery options for SharePoint databases](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/supported-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-options-for-sharepoint-databas)